# How to do for loop with a list that contains lists with another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with sublists that are lists. It looks like this one:

```
original_list = [['ab','cd','ef'],['bd','ij','lm'],['ij','uv','st'],['df','hi','jk']]
```

and another list to check:

```
check_list = ['ab','cd','ij','st']
```

I want to keep only elements that are not in the check_list, the result should be like this:

```
result = [['ef'],['bd','lm'],['uv'],['df','hi','jk']]
```

The result should have the number of `len()` equal to the original list's `len()`.

I tried to use a `for` loop, but still cannot figure how to get the result correctly:

```
keep_result = []
result = []

for i in original_list:
  for sub_i in i:
      if sub_i not in check_list:
        keep_result.append(sub_i)
  result.append(keep_result)
```

Comment: well where is your current code ? this seems to be a pretty easy task.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: What’s wrong with your current code? What have you done to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy. Here's the elegant solution.

```
original_list = [['ab','cd','ef'],['bd','ij','lm'],['ij','uv','st'],['df','hi','jk']]
check_list = ['ab','cd','ij','st']

result = [[elem for elem in sub_list if elem not in check_list] for sub_list in 
original_list]

print(result)
# result = [['ef'],['bd','lm'],['uv'],['df','hi','jk']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension inside a `for` loop to remove elements in each nested list that are in `check_list`:

```
original_list = [['ab','cd','ef'],['bd','ij','lm'],['ij','uv','st'],['df','hi','jk']]

check_list = ['ab','cd','ij','st']

filtered_list = []
for y in original_list:
    filtered_list.append([x for x in y if x not in check_list])
```

Output:

```
[['ef'], ['bd', 'lm'], ['uv'], ['df', 'hi', 'jk']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension is the Pythonic way of doing it:

```
original_list = [['ab','cd','ef'],['bd','ij','lm'],['ij','uv','st'],['df','hi','jk']]
check_list = ['ab','cd','ij','st']

result = [[val for val in inner_list if val not in check_list] for inner_list in original_list]

assert result == [['ef'],['bd','lm'],['uv'],['df','hi','jk']]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is brute-force solution:

```
original_list = [['ab','cd','ef'],['bd','ij','lm'],['ij','uv','st'],['df','hi','jk']]

check_list = ['ab','cd','ij','st']

buffer_list = list()

for x in original_list:
    for y in x:
        if(y not in check_list):
            buffer_list.append(y)
print(buffer_list)
```

Comment: It didn't return the result that I wanted, by the way, thanks for the answer